# Azure ServiceBus Queue active messages counter broken?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

We have an issue with ServiceBus service. We have a Queue that contains messages, also we have Continuous WebJob that has OnMessage listener for new messages, everithing works fine, but there is one strange problem. Active message counter never shows less then [2789 Active Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4kGT.png) in Queue. New messages recieved correcly. We tried to recieve messages by Recieve method, but result is the same. Seems something wrong with counter.

Queue configuration:

- Message time to live (default) - 14 days
- Lock duration - 30 sec.
- Duplicate detection history - 10 min
- Maximum Delivery Count - 10
- Maximum size - not set
- Queue state - Active
- Relocate to Dead letter - not enabled
- Current Size - 3447.3994140625 KB
- Updated at - 12.01.2017, 11:56:40
- Enable Partitioning - true

Any ideas will be helpfull.

> ## SOLVED:

Those messages were in Defer state, we used `QueueClient.Peek()` to get the message, then

```
var m = QueueClient.Recieve(message.SequenceNumber);
m.Complete();
```

and messages are Gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These messages might be deferred. Which means they are Active, but won't be automatically delivered to OnMessage. You need to know their sequence number to process them in a specific way, see documentation on how. Or you can use Service Bus Explorer tool to look at the messages directly, and or re-process them as necessary.